# Businness Central 401 unauthorized access

Tags: powershell, web-services, soapui, gsoap, dynamics-business-central

I need access to web services provided by an installation of Business Central on Premise.
BC is installed on a windows server 2022 without domain (no active directory present).

Attempts to log in via SoapUI return the 401 Unauthorized.

I also tried to access through an application written in C that uses the gSoap libraries and I get the same message:

```
    Error 401 fault: SOAP-ENV:Server [no subcode] 
    "HTTP Error" Detail: HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
```

Instead if I try to access via the following powershell script:

```
$username = "myUser"
$password = "MyPasswd"

$URI = "http://localhost:8012/ERP/WS/Vendor/Page/SalesOrder"
$cred = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList @($username,(ConvertTo-SecureString -String $password -AsPlainText -Force))
$WSProxy = New-WebServiceProxy -Uri $URI -Credential $cred
$WSProxy.ReadMultiple($null, "", 0)
```

access is granted and I keep the response data provided by Business Central.

What do I have to configure in Business Central, in an on-premise installation without a Windows domain, to guarantee access to soapUI (or an application developed using gSoap) ?

Comment: See following : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/business-central/dev-itpro/administration/users-credential-types

Comment: @jdweng Do you know why connection through powershell is allowed?

Comment: Allowed or Not allowed?  Problem either way has nothing to do with powershell.  You are making a HTTP Request and a request through any application is the same provided the URL, headers, and body are the same and TLS is working properly.  My best guess is you need to use HTTPS instead of HTTP.

Comment: How can I force Business Central to use http ?

Comment: Latest version is probably already expecting HTTPS.  Just change your URL from HTTP to HTTPS.

Comment: I don't understand "latest version is probably already expecting HTTPS", but if I use powershel the access is granted via http (see script $URI = "http://localhost:8012/ERP/WS/Vendor/Page/SalesOrder"), but it is not granted for SoapUI.

Comment: Useful info.  The no subcode indicates the server did not specify fault in the response.  did you try HTTPS?  Error 401 indicates the server did not process request due to a credential error.  SOAP is different protocol than a HTTP request and may have different requirements.  You can check server error logs to get more info : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/business-central/dev-itpro/administration/monitor-server-events-windows-event-log

Comment: Issue may be OAUTH.  Soap requires OAUTH credentials.  See : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/business-central/dev-itpro/webservices/authenticate-web-services-using-oauth

Comment: Which authentication type is the Service Tier configured for? Windows or NavUserPassword?

Comment: @kaspermoerch The authentication type is Windows

Answer (score 0):

I can suppose that your BC Server has "Use NTLM Authentication" option not enabled.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).